# Error with ngx-translate and Auth0 authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0, ngx-translate

I made a project in Angular 8 and included both ngx-translate (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) and a login using Auth0 (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login#install-the-sdk). They work well separately but I have an odd error when they are together.

I get this error for each translated text of html in my project in console.

```
core.js:6014 ERROR 
{error: "login_required", error_description: "Login required", state: "aGNHczdqZTRjMzFTM3ZtWnpIOS1kQjdXaXV2dktyVW94ZkdsYm5KVGhRSA=="}
error: "login_required"
error_description: "Login required"
state: "aGNHczdqZTRjMzFTM3ZtWnpIOS1kQjdXaXV2dktyVW94ZkdsYm5KVGhRSA=="
__proto__: Object
```

When I comment the provider in my app.module.ts of the Interceptor I made to add the token in my backend requests the translation works well and everything is fine. But then my token won't be sent to the backend for my requests.

```
providers: [
    // {
    //   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    //   useClass: InterceptorService,
    //   multi: true
    // }
  ]
```

And when I comment the default language in my AppComponent I have no more errors the token is sent to the backend in my requests. But then I dont see the text in my frontend because its not translated.

```
export class AppComponent {  
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    // translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }
}
```

At first the error seems to indicate that I'm not logged in, but it does the same thing when I log in.

Here is the code of my Interceptor class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from './authentication/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  public intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.authService.getTokenSilently$().pipe(
      mergeMap(token => {
        const tokenReq = req.clone({
          setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        });
        return next.handle(tokenReq);
      }),
      catchError(err => throwError(err))
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I work with the Auth0 Community. This doesn't sound directly related to Auth0 as it sounds like you are successfully confirming your state/session. I'm not 100% familiar with NGX Translate but I did find a tutorial on this front that may help you out. I apologize I can't provide more insight on this front.

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular8-app-with-ngx-translate